# Problem with Images on TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have a TreeView with ItemHeight=16 and CheckBoxes=true. I want to show images that are 8x16 pixels in size on the nodes. But when I do this, the "Plus/Minus" and "CheckBoxes" change their size (get smaller).

How can I fix this? I don't want to use a 16x16 image because I don't want to loose those 8 pixels with white space.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "I don't want to loose those 8 pixels with white space.". Could you explain a little bit more what you mean by that?

Comment: I want text, checkboxes and plus/minus to be the correct size, so I choose TreeView.ItemHeight=16. If I want images, I must associate the TreeView with an ImageList that contains 16x16 pixel images. The picture I wanna show is only 8 pixels wide. The way the TreeView works, the size of the CheckBox and plus/minus is according to the image's width.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a bug. Checkbox size and plus/minus size shouldn't be affected by the image size. Check with MS and see if they have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [TreeViewAdv for .Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/treeviewadv/) it comes with huge amounts of awesome, and should solve your problem...